# Captive portal in java or c#

Tags: java, c#

I have been trying to write a captive portal in java but i don't know where to start, i have done researched on search engines but i haven't seen any tutorial on how to start. I don't need someone to write codes for me, all i need is a a way of making my server get all the `HTTP` request from the wifi adapter and reply with my custom landing page. I have tried setting up a `ServerSocket` but that does not solve my problem, What am looking for is a `Socket` to accept http connections and authenticate users.
Answers can be posted in java or c#

Comment: Please give an example for what you want to achieve (which requests to catch where).

Comment: "What am looking for is a `Socket` to accept http connections and authenticate users.". But you just said that you don't want to use `ServerSocket`. Try to make up your mind.

Comment: I think this question is too broad and should be closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a DNS server.
when network users sent request to reach IP of a specific host name; redirect them to your captive portal web service in a specific IP.
obviously your DHCP shall be configured on your DNS server IP.
you can use arsoft.tools.net in c# library to create your arbitrary DNS server.
And also you can authorize users with a time limit or with username and password in your captive portal page.

Answer (score 0):

The most known solution for this is using an OS with a great routing and firewall managers. After all you will have o manage the new incoming connections and properly manage them. You can read about well known [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/), it's a great solution.

A work around of this is using a software that connects directly to an server (via socket) and manage the new connection (client) of it's requests made by the client software.